# Is there any ayah (quran ayat) which has been revealed by dream?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, dream, ayah

Do we know prophet Muhammad has got any divine inspiration by a dream?

Comment: a verse has been revealed in a dream

Comment: For now I need to say nope. But maybe somebody else knows an answer or would be faster in finding it.

Comment: @Medi1Saif could you find an answer? How about http://quran.com/17/60 and http://quran.com/48/27 doesn't الرأيا mean dream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the problem with a revelation in a dream is that while a dream may be a kind of revelation we don't have any knowledge of any verse of the Quran revealed this way and could only know about it if our Messenger told us about it. However he has been shown many signs of things which would happen later before they happened, but as far as I understood OP's question this was not asked. I'll quote some verses which have been quoted in the comments and others which seem to be dream revelations.

**About verse [17:60](http://legacy.quran.com/17/60)**

For the quote from this Verse:

> ...And We did not make the sight which We showed you except as a trial for the people, as was the accursed tree [mentioned] in the Qur'an. ...

we have a sahih [hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/180510) on the authority of ibn 'Abbas saying it is referring to an eye witness of our Prophet at the night of israa'. So it doesn't refer to a dream at all.

**About verse 48:27**

Ibn Kathir said, about this verse:

> In a dream, the Messenger of Allah saw himself entering Makkah and performing Tawaf around the House. He told his Companions about this dream when he was still in Al-Madinah. When they went to Makkah in the year of Al-Hudaybiyyah, none of them doubted that the Prophet's vision would come true that year. When the treaty of peace was conducted and they had to return to Al-Madinah that year, being allowed to return to Makkah the next year, some of the Companions disliked what happened. 'Umar bin Al-Khattab asked about this, saying, "Haven't you told us that we will go to the House and perform Tawaf around it'' The Prophet said,
> (Yes. Have I told you that you will go to it this year) 'Umar said, "No." The Prophet said, (Then you will go to it and perform Tawaf around it.) 'Umar received the same answer from Abu Bakr As-Siddiq, letter for letter. This is why Allah the Exalted and Most honored said, (Indeed Allah shall fulfill the true vision which He showed to His Messenger in very truth. Certainly, you shall enter Al-Masjid Al-Haram, if Allah wills,)  ...  ([qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2004&Itemid=104))

Imam at-Tabari in his tafsir quoted ahadith and narrations of Mujahid, Qatadah, ibn 'Abbas and ibn Ishaaq and explained them saying that this dream occurred at the time before the treaty of hudaibiyah and our Messenger told his companions about it, when this didn't happen and the the people were asked to slaughter in hudaibiyah although they neither performed hajj nor 'omrah some monafeqeen (hypocrites) and disbelievers asked them mocking: were's Muhammad's vision?

So this is a true Vision our Prophet has been given and it happened!

**Surat al-Kawthar 108**

The possibility of this surah being revealed by a dream is based on a hadith

> One day the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) was sitting amongst us that he dozed off. He then raised his head smilingly. We said: What makes you smile. Messenger of Allah? He said: A Sura has just been revealed to me, and then recited: In the name of Allah, the Compassionate, the Merciful. Verily We have given thee Kauthar (fount of abundance). ... (sahih [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/4/56))

As-Suyuti in his itqan quoted ar-Rafi'i who at first sight seemed to explain this hadith as a revelation by dream, but than he concluded

> that most seemingly it is said that the whole Quran has been revealed in wakefulness

And explained that what seemed to be a nap or a doz off for the sahaba or more exactly for Anas (who apparently saw this the first time), was apparently the kind of absence or state of absence that our Prophet experienced after a revelation based on ahadith like in sahih [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/43) and sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/52/25) (where this state was called الْبُرَحَاءِ).