# Revelations which Holy Prophet (may peace be upon him) directly received from Allah

Tags: quran, revelation

Aoa sir...
i want to know another thing about revelation that .Sir we all know that Holy Quran was not revealed fully through Angel jibreel there are some verses which Allah almighty himself revealed on Holy prophet directly like verse 286 of surah baqarah and many more.but in surah baqarah verse 97 allah says that

> Say,
> "Whoever is an enemy to Gabriel - it is [none but] he who has brought the Qur'an down upon your heart, [O Muhammad], by permission of Allah, confirming that which was before it and as guidance and good tidings for the believers."

and in surah nahl Allah says,

> "Say, [O Muhammad], "The Pure Spirit has brought it down from your Lord in truth to make firm those who believe and as guidance and good tidings to the Muslims."

so in both verses Allah is saying that Holy Quran was revealed through angel jibreel by permission of Allah but we know that there are some verses which allah revealed directly to Prophet Muhammad[S.A.W].
Plz explain this to me.A nxiouly waiting...for

Comment: The question answers itself. The angel is pretty much the mailman, the message delivered, is from Allah.

Comment: What's the issue exactly? Jibril (AS) did bring most of the Quran as those verses are saying.

Comment: Both verses you've quoted only support the revelation by intermediate of Jibreel. I don't really get your question do you want examples of verses revealed without intermediate or an evidence for revelation without an intermediate? [Is there any ayah quran ayat which has been revealed by dream?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33556/is-there-any-ayah-quran-ayat-which-has-been-revealed-by-dream) could be relevant

Comment: So you basically say this but we know that there are some verses which allah revealed directly to Prophet Muhammad[S.A.W] can you show me the verses that you claim